# Is it a good idea to get user data from local storage and not from API?

Tags: api, local-storage

I need to show logged in user's profile image in the header. But I don't want to call API on every page where header stands. Is it a good idea to store current user information in local storage? So I can immediately get profile image and display in the header without an extra network traffic.

Comment: Yes, it's generally a good idea to keep some user data in local storage.  Images, sure.  Password, no.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always get it from the local storage, then how do you want to make sure that they are up to date? I think that's one of the problems which single page applications try to solve it.

Comment: I am using refresh tokens for my app. When user get a new token, data in the local storage will update. Only problem is refreshing a token is occured every 5-10 minutes. So when user update his profile, changes will effect after some time

Comment: The thing you are doing with the refresh token seems weird to me, and it is against your optimization practices. Why do you refresh your tokens every 5 minutes? And if you use OAuth, it means that you are using a RestAPI. Then, why don't you store your user info in something like redux and refresh it on the next visits or update requests?